# sharing a common folder among ec2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

what is the simplest way to share a physical folder, among all ec2 instances,

e.g. /tmp/images/ folder I want to have this folder some where and be accessible to all my instances

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options.

Using S3 is most common choice for a situation like this. But it depends what you are doing with the data. Since its not a block device, it wont work in certain use cases.

The other option is to use NFS. You can set up an NFS share on one of your instances and mount it on all your other instances. Keep in mind that you need to keep security locked down on the NFS ports

Comment: thanks datasage, I think I will go for NFS. I just want to share a few files among all my instances.